# WebViewでPC表示にする方法

Tags: android, webview

Android開発初心者です。
WebViewでPC表示にさせる方法が解りません。
UserAgentを変える、というのがヒットしましたが、具体的な方法が解りません。

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View inputView = factory.inflate(R.layout.wiki_job_dialog, null);

WebView webView1 = (WebView) inputView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});
webView1.loadUrl("http://seesaawiki.jp/rgbyserver/d/Job%B0%EC%CD%F7%B5%DA%A4%D3%C7%BD%CE%CF%C0%E2%CC%C0%A1%AA");
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(inputView);

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

なおブラウザではなく、一つのサイトを表示させます。

Answer (score 1):

ユーザーエージェントは次のコードで取得・設定ができます。

```
webView1.getSetting().getUserAgentString(); //取得
webView1.getSetting().setUserAgentString(); //設定
```

PC版のページを表示させるにはPCブラウザが使っているユーザーエージェントを設定すれば可能だと思います。
ユーザーエージェントの表記については以下のサイトなどが役に立つと思います。
[userAgent一覧/ユーザーエージェント一覧](http://www.openspc2.org/userAgent/)